# C++/CLI/C# Map generic types to template types

Tags: c#, c++, templates, generics, command-line-interface

When writing CLI code to interface between C++ and C#, you often have to convert certain types in function calls so that they can be used in C# or C++. For example, std::string obviously doesn't exist in C#, so you have to convert it to String^ and vice versa.

Now I want to wrap a C++ class that exposes a templated function into C# via an interface that should expose a similar generic method. For this I wrote a CLI ref class that implements the C# interface and holds a pointer to an instance of the C++ class:

```
// C#
public interface ISomeClass {
    void SomeMethod<T>(T param);
}

//CLI
public ref class : ISomeClass {
public:
    generic<typename T>
    virtual void SomeMethod(T param) {
        _nativePtr->NativeMethod<T>(param); // :(
    }
    // Implementation details...
};

// C++
class SomeNativeClass {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void NativeMethod(T&& nativeParam) { /*bla*/ }
};
```

In my specific case (using Visual Studio 2013), this makes the compiler crash. Even though I don't think it is supposed to crash, I can guess that this is not supposed to work, after all I can't pass C# types directly into a C++ function. What I want is some mechanism through which I can convert a generic type 'T' into a C++ template type 'U'. I tried using template metaprogramming, however this does not work with C# generics in CLI, since generic classes can't be specialized.

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: You can't make this work.  There is no mapping from the *managed* T type to the *unmanaged* T template argument.  Nor can templates be specialized at runtime like generics can.  This must be sorted out at compile-time.  If you're stuck with the template then you have to give up on generics.

Comment: The rough C++ equivalent of C# generics is type erasure, not templates.  templates can be used to implement type erasure, and generics have syntax similar to templates, but they are otherwise not that related.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, that does indeed confirm my fears. I guess I will have to rethink my design in that case :)